# usage of "and" in stead of "comma" in a sentence

Tags: punctuation

> 1.They did not add these extra hours and minutes and seconds.
>
> 2.They did not add these extra hours, minutes, and seconds.

Are there any difference in these two sentences when using "and" instead of comma in a list?

Comment: The sentence with the comma is better, as when speaking you would not say "and" repeatedly.

Answer (score 2):

It is uncommon to use multiple “and”s in a list, but in writing it is sometimes done for literary effect. It sounds somewhat childish, like the author hasn’t learned how to make proper lists yet. But when context shows the author clearly has a grasp of the language, we know it is done on purpose rather than an error.

In speech, it is somewhat more common. We initially think we’re only listing two items, so we use “and”, but then we think of a third item, use “and” again, and can’t go back in time to unsay the first “and”.

Answer (score 1):

**Commas Rules**
Use commas to separate words and word groups in a simple series of three or more items. Like in your sentence:
They did not add these extra hours, minutes, and seconds.
This is the correct way to write it.

Another example like:
We had coffee, cheese and crackers and grapes.
In this case we have to use **Oxford Comma** (when the last comma in a series comes before and or or)
We  had coffee, cheese and crackers, and grapes.
Adding a comma after crackers make it clear that cheese and crackers represents one dish.
**Conclusion**
Use comma to separate adjectives, nouns, verbs, words, word groups and use and just before the last item unless it is needed.
Example:
To make her famous muffins, Paulette bought fresh broccoli, baker's chocolate, flour, sugar, and eggs.

References:
[The item in a Series-Grammar Bytes](http://www.chompchomp.com/terms/iteminaseries.htm)
[GrammarBook.com](http://www.grammarbook.com/punctuation/commas.asp)

Answer (score 1):

Apart from grammar, I think English writers don't want to repeat the same word over and over again it sounds boring, so it's better to just add a comma when something is repeated. In your sentence instead of repeating "and" each time just put a comma and be done with it.